# How did my website break after deploying it?

Tags: php

Why did all my require_once calls that are written with paths like ../.../ this folder/thifile.php broke as soon as I deployed my website?

Are they wrong? On the localhost they were working just fine.

I got his errorfailed to open stream: No such file or directory in , and my file structure has not changed after I deployed it

Comment: To get an answer, you (probably) need to edit your question with an example `require_once` call, and the directory structure of your website.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the files and folders being called by `require_once();` were uploaded to the server?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the paths point to the same places? If you have a different directory structure on your deployed site, relative paths like "../../etc" may not point to the same files.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't bring my chrystal ball, so you might need to explain some more, but

- You host has a different system than you (windows vs linux?), so the / and \ are not compatible?
- There was some other problem (hard to guess, since you didn't provide an error)
- Not enough rights to read the files
- A virtual directory, so you can't go back in the structure like that, cause you're getting a different (real) dir?

Comment: Windows recognizes /. `C:/my/dir` is valid, you just can't do it on the command line because DOS uses / as its argument flag character.

Answer (score 0):

Its definitely a path issue. Try going to the files u included using http://yourdomain/path/you/included